# how to find odoo default addons when I installed by docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, odoo

I installed odoo on docker and I want to know the path of default addons I Didn't find him
so I do a lot of search  but didn't find him so how to find odoo default addons when I installed by docker
after installed odoo on docker I want to see where is the path of default addons

Comment: I think that's OS dependent, but you will see the paths to the default addons on odoo start in the server log of odoo. For example on debian systems it's `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons`.